# mysql queries more than one table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One `attendance` table and one `lessons` table. I want to print out within my page all the student ids from the attendance table where `'register' is = 'y'` within the `lessons` table.

basically, print out * from `table 1` if in table two a specific column is a specific value.

please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to `JOIN` the tables on the `student_id`:

```
select a.student_id
from attendance a
inner join lessons l
  on a.student_id = l.student_id
where l.register = 'y'
```

The syntax used in this query is an `INNER JOIN` which will return all matching rows between both tables where the lesson register column has a value of `y`.

Comment: why the a. and the 1. before column names?

Comment: @user2111820 Those are table aliases.

Comment: @user2111820 Yes, if you do not use aliases, then you would use `attendance.student_id`.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT attendance_details.student_id, attendance_details.lesson_id, 
     lesson_details.lesson_id, lesson_details.register
   FROM attendance_details 
   INNER JOIN lesson_details
   ON attendance_details.lesson_id = lesson_details.lesson_id 
   WHERE lesson_details = 'y'";

Comment: thankyou so much, that worked. for more information on inner join guys visit: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) operator to join multiple tables on a foreign key.